# Where and how to set element manual focus

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

In LWC, **lightning-input tabindex=0** not work as expected, the cursor does not focus on the textbox. So decided to set the focus manually, check my syntax

```
<lightning-input type="text" onchange={handleOnChange}  tabindex="0" label="Enter some text" name="fname" class={testFocus}></lightning-input>

let temp = this.template.querySelector("lightning-input");
temp.focus();
```

Want to know where to set the manual focus process on lifecycle hook, I can not set it **constructor and connectedCallback** because the element is not loaded yet, also can not set the getter process like

```
get testFocus() {
    let temp = this.template.querySelector("lightning-input");
        temp.focus();
    return "temp";
}
```

can not use **renderedCallback** because it will attempt to set the focus after every rerendering.

What to do where to set the manual focus process.

Comment: you can try conditional renderedcallback. Example flag == false, then set focus() .

Answer (score 0):

What about...

```
    ...
    _rendered = false;
    renderedCallback() {
        if(this._rendered === false) {
            this._rendered = true;
            this.template.querySelector("lightning-input").focus();
        }
    }
    ...
```